# Spring Boot Intercept Request as early as possible

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application, and I can easily write an interceptor something like `RequestBodyAdviceAdapter` that will allow me to intercept the incoming request.  The problem with this approach is that it seems to intercept things right before the @Controller class...  Is there something that will intercept a request very early on?  Like before LDAP Authentication.  I have a pointcut that is intercepting some things before my `RequestBodyAdviceAdapter`, but havent found any other ways to intercept things before my `RequestBodyAdviceAdapter`.  Thus my question is, is there something that exist, or explains what happens before the @Controller and how I could possibly intercept it like right as soon as the request actually enters into my service long before the @Controller?

Thanks,

Comment: If you to intercept before the RequestBodyAdviceAdapter,so what's the utility of the interceptor provided by spring boot? or you can make some AOP implementation

Comment: Not sure I understand you comment could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using filters.  Specifically in this instance a [OncePerRequestFilter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-onceperrequestfilter) can be used.